# Google Apps Spreadsheet open specific sheet based on week number

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet, week-number

I know the solution "move sheet to the most left" to make it default when opening spreadsheet.

Thing is that I got one spreadsheet per week, and it's quite messy to move around like that, plus it will be much more user friendly.

Something similar to this 
[Google Apps Spreadsheet open specific sheet based on current date (Month)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213555/google-apps-spreadsheet-open-specific-sheet-based-on-current-date-month?newreg=e4a6327d70f642dfb54af3a107246903)

Weeknum is a rather new function in google docs, so I haven't found anything else googling around.